# Swift 4 - How to sort array of dictionaries with value of any

Tags: swift4

I have an array of dictionaries.

The dictionaries have 3 strings in them and 1 number.

```
var allScores = [[String:Any]]()
var scoreDict = [String:Any]()
scoreDict["Score"] = score as Int
scoreDict["Designation"] = designation
scoreDict["Name"] = name
scoreDict["Emoji"] = emoji
allScores.append(scoreDict)
```

How do I sort on Score in descending order?

I have tried

```
allScores.sort(by: {$0.Score.compare($1.Score, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending})
```

But I get the error

> Value of type '[String:Any]'has no member 'Score'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access dictionaries with dot notation and you cannot sort `Int` values with `compare:options:`

Use key subscription, type cast and the `>` operator.

```
allScores.sort(by: {($0["Score"] as! Int) > $1["Score"] as! Int})
```

You are encouraged to use a custom struct rather than a dictionary

```
struct Score {
    let score : Int
    let destination : String
    let name : String
    let emoji : String
}

var allScores = [Score]()
```

then you can use dot notation

```
allScores.sort(by: {$0.score > $1.score })
```

Comment: Thank you! I am writing scores to a pList later so that's why I'm using a dictionary.

Comment: In Swift 4 you can write structs to plist very comfortable with the `Codable` protocol.